# hook_menu not rendering page or form

Tags: 6, routes

I'm using 6, and I CANNOT get hook_menu to take me to the page where the form is. I go to www.myurl.com/test_form (and for good measure, www.myurl.com/?q=test_form) to check.

If I clear the caches, then I get a WSOD. If I don't, I get a 404. I have changed permissions and cleared caches and tried to figure out what Drupal wants with no luck. What did I do wrong?

```
function module__menu() {
      $items = array();
      $items['test_form'] = array(
            'title' => 'New Form',
            'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
            'page arguments' => array('module_form'),
            'description' => 'Form',
            'access callback' => TRUE,
            'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
      );
      return $items;
}

function module_form($form_state) {
$form = array();

    //my form stuff.....

    return $form;
}
```

UPDATE: Thanks for the advice. Did what you guys said. Still no luck. Error log doesn't show any errors either, so I'm totally lost here.

Comment: Is this your actual code and is your module named module? I kind of assumed module_menu() was really going to be something like pajarotis_menu() in your code, but perhaps this is exactly what your code is. I don't think you can use "module" as the name of a module.

Answer (score 3):

You've got two underscores in your menu function declaration, try changing it to:

```
function module_menu() {
```

Other than that your code is fine, although on the off chance you're using this module to create a custom content type I'd recommend changing the name of your callback function so you don't get a collision with [`hook_form()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer%21hooks%21node.php/function/hook_form/6).

Comment: Beat me to it :)

Comment: no, just want to make a simple form that i hope to make dynamic with AHAH.

Answer (score 2):

You have 2 underscores in hook_menu():

```
function module__menu() {
```

should be

```
function module_menu() {
```

Edit: Also, your module name should not be "module" (in the assumption that the code you provided is your actual code). Also `hook_form()` is already a Drupal hook so you should not be using a function called `mymodule_form` to provide your own standalone form. Try `mymodule_form_description_form()`.

Answer (score 1):

Try clearing the cache; it happened a lot of times to me, due to the menu being cached.

Comment: done that. and also the admin/build/modules trick. nothing

Comment: try commenting the current page callback & page argument to point to something that prints a simple test message... see if that gets registered and prints the message in the page... if it works revert code and check with your form.. i'd also suggest you to manually truncate the cache tables once... this happens to be my ritual.. though less logical it works for me.. hope it does something similar to you